# Cannot access a class in project's root

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-5.0

I have a configuration class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace VCProjectHost
{
    public static class Configs
    {
        public static string SiteName { get; set; }

        static Configs()
        {
            SiteName = "Ahmadali Shafiee's Projects Host";
        }
    }
}
```

and this is part of my `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<title>
    @{
        Write(ViewBag.Title);
        if (ViewBag.Title != null)
        {
            Write(" | ");
        }
        Write(VCProjectHost.Configs.SiteName);
    }
</title>
```

but the `Write(VCProjectHost.Configs.SiteName);` throws an error saying that `Configs` doesn't exist!

Comment: @LastCoder: He's using the fully qualified name so a using statement is not needed (that would make it nicer to read though)

Comment: @LastCoder if you read the code you'll see 1. I'm using razor view engine and 2. the `using` isn't necessary!

Comment: @ahmadali shafiee - good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is you haven't specified a visibility modifier on your class therefore by default it would be `internal`. Try changing it to:

```
public static class Configs
{
   ...
}
```

**Update**

Looking at all the things you have tried I am struggling to see what the issue could be. As a temporary work around you could just pass in the site name as part of the ViewBag (like you are already doing with the title).

Comment: no! I've edited the question and I remove `public` by mistake. In the project it's OK!

Comment: Hmm I can only assume it's an issue with the class being situated at the root of the site. If you move it to say the *Models* folder/re-compile does it work ok?

Comment: I moved it into `models` folder but the problems doesn't resolved!

Comment: Can you access the static class from the controller?

Comment: No! I can't access it from controller too!

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee this is clearly a visibility/compilation issue. Try creating a new static class and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the class for some reason doesn't end up in the web site? If it's in a separate project, ensure that the DLL file generated by the project exists in your bin directory. If it's in the same project, make sure its build action is set to "Compile" in the project file properties.

Comment: it's inside of my project. in project's properties in build tab the Configuration is `Active (Debug)`

Comment: I was talking about the per-file build action, not the project-wide build configuration. But I guess you solved it anyways (creating a new file might've just set the build action correctly)

Comment: Thank, I was looking for a reason that why creating a new file resolved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the 'Build Action' of your class file is set to 'Compile' (right click file in solution explorer and choose properties).